# how to update or change roles of default admin user on Mongodb once its created?

Tags: mongodb

I just setup a 3 node MongdoDB cluster with replicasets and made a novice mistake. I setup the replica set etc first and then was being fancy and setup the default admin user as below:

> show users
>      {
>              "_id" : ObjectId("blah"),
>               "user" : "admin",
>           "pwd" : "blah",
>           "roles" : [
>                   "userAdminAnyDatabase"
>           ]
>   }

This is fine for basic admin but I cannot do any replica set commands as the role is not cluster admin:

> rs.status()
>   { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" }

I tried a few things

- adding a new user with a different set of roles but that did not work either.
- tried to use the update role for admin role - that did not work

> db.users.update({'user':'admin'}, {$addToSet: {'roles' :'clusterAdmin'}})
>   not authorized for update on admin.users
>   
>   Any other thoughts on this one - outside of redoing the setup for mongo?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add "clusterAdmin" role to your admin user, more doc can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/)